# assigning values from a lookup table in many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have the following tables:

```
Persons(
PersonID,
FirstName,
LastNAme)

Person_Categories(
CategoryID,
CategoryName)

Persons_PersonCategories(
PersonID,
CategoryID)
```

One person can have more than one category and many people can belong to one category.
I want to be able to assign categories to persons from a drop down menu (Person_Categories). I've written the following query which displays data if there are already categories assigned to persons.

```
SELECT Persons_PersonCategories.PrsCatID, PrsCategory
FROM Person_Categories
INNER JOIN Persons_PersonCategories
ON Persons_PersonCategories.PrsCatID = Person_Categories.PrsCatID;
```

My question: What sql statement do I need to assign categories from the Person_Categories table to Persons?

Many thanks, zan

Comment: technically speaking, "many to many" relationship cant exist.. if it does, then you have your design messed up.

Comment: @Bhrugesh Patel, what about Products to Orders? Students to Classes? Messed up?

Comment: @zan, are you looking for an insert statement or a select?

Comment: @ Tim, I'm looking for a select statement as I don't want change but draw values Person_Categories. This is the bit where I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Tim, Its Order -> Products & they r never really directly connected. They are connected by OrderLine Table & same goes for any relationship you can think of that looks like many to many. Not putting you down or something like that, its just the way it is.

Comment: @Bhrugesh you may be confusing the model with its implementation in a relational database. No offense taken, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user selects a category from the menu list, you can assign it to a person with:

```
INSERT INTO Persons_PersonCategories (PersonID, CategoryID)
VALUES (<person ID>, <category ID>);
```

where *<person ID>* and *<category ID>* respectively represent the person you are assigning to and the category the user has choosen.

To remove a category from a given person, you can use:

```
DELETE FROM Persons_PersonCategories
WHERE PersonID   = <person ID>
  AND CategoryID = <category ID>;
```

where *<person ID>* and *<category ID>* respectively represent the person you are removing categories from and the category the user is removing.

Hope this helps.